# Email preferences page broken on mobile; can't set email preferences

Tags: bug, design, badges, mobile-web

When in the email settings, neither the badge colours show up or the name placement seem right as the image below illustrates:

[image]

**Note:** This is on the mobile site.

I gained access to the page after receiving an email in regards to the Salary Calculator and like many I was not interested so I clicked the 'Unsubscribe' (from emails) link and it took me to the page shown in the above picture.

Some points from [Martijn Pieters](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters), [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358101/email-preferences-page-broken-on-mobile-cant-set-email-preferences?noredirect=1#comment524307_358101) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358101/email-preferences-page-broken-on-mobile-cant-set-email-preferences?noredirect=1#comment524345_358101).

Comment: @MartijnPieters undeleted. Has anyone been able to replicate this?

Comment: I don't even know where to find the email preferences in the mobile web. I could get there from the full site and then switch to mobile with the footer link, and then can see that that page is very, very broken in the mobile view. I'm guessing that that page was never meant to be used from the mobile web.(

Comment: So the question then is: how did you end up there?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I received an email about the salary calculator and I clicked the link which allows you to unsubscribe from emails and it took me to that page.

Comment: That's a great piece of context to add to the question! Linking to a page from an email is, in my view, an excellent reason to require a page to be mobile friendly.

Comment: @MartijnPieters updated the the body as requested and the title.

Comment: You can't go back to the full site either, since the page is not a mobile-specific version there is no link to the full site! This is very broken UX for anyone handling email on mobile.